# Are there any flat plates with beveled or sharp edges?

Tags: technic, piece-information, building, moc

I'm currently making a functional minifigure-scaled escalator that ideally move like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAjFw7v8QhE). Progress has been made on both the stair slope and staircase design (both respectively pictured below), and now I'm working on a sort of guide for the staircase to transition into flat platform.
[image: Stud.io rendition, profile] [image: Staircase design]

However, I've come to an issue regarding the height of the guide being 1 plate thick, as I've yet to find any flat plates or bricks of plate width with the appropriate bevel to prevent the staircase shafts from getting snagged. Currently, the only "beveled" plates that I could think of is the [22385 pentagonal plate](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=22385&name=Tile,%20Modified%202%20x%203%20Pentagonal&category=%5BTile,%20Modified%5D#T=C), and the [15070 modified plate with tooth](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=15070#T=C) and its other variants.

Are there any other kinds of "beveled" bricks should I know of or any legal building techniques that can create a sturdy plate-width edge or slope that could be utilized here? Either way, I want a result such as this image (note the red plates and the drawn-in edge):

[image: red guiding plate, with edge]

Here is another view of the overhang, and also beveling attempt using the pentagon plate:
[image: red guiding overhang with pentagon plate]

It is paramount that this guiding overhang is 1 stud in width or shorter, 1 flat plate tall, and built using only legal techniques.

I am also aware of the [dedicated escalator piece](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=69900&name=Technic,%20Link%20Chain,%20Large%20with%20Panel%20and%20Center%20Divider%20(Escalator%20Link)&category=%5BTechnic,%20Link%5D#T=C&C=86) but I won't be using it due to the complex nature of my build.

EDIT: This might be an illegal technique, but I might have found a method for sloping, which utilizes a panel atop 1x1 brick with stud on the side and a 1x1 headlight brick joined at the side. This is the base, with the two snot pieces forming an offset stud arrangement on top.

[image: Offset base, with 1x1 headlight and 1x1 stud on the side]

And this is the base with the panel connected with the two studs, making it slanted.
[image: Offset base, with panel applied]

While I have tested this with my available bricks and it works, I still don't know if it's a legal building technique or not, so please inform me.

EDIT 2: I was informed by @Sander De Dycker that this building method is illegal, as the top studs are slightly further away than normal. However, since this slanted panel is very close to my desired outcome in terms of angle (280 degrees as Stud.io informed), I am in search of legal building techniques that produces the same result.

Comment: There is 49668 Plate, Modified 1 x 1 with Tooth Horizontal, would that work? Or alternatively 4740 Dish 2 x 2 Inverted (Radar)…

Comment: There are some other fangs in addition to what @PhilB. mentioned... but I don't think they would work as most have stud above sloped part.

Comment: Your updated question asks whether what you suggest is an illegal building technique. "illegal" is typically shorthand for "puts stress on the brick(s)". And this does, since the two studs the panel attaches to are slightly farther apart than normal. So it would be "illegal". Though, in the end, it's up to you if and how you want to stress your bricks :)

Comment: Okay then. At least I think I have a lead on my issue now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** After testing out the design with physical bricks, I have come to the conclusion that my iteration using the [22385 pentagonal plate](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=22385&name=Tile,%20Modified%202%20x%203%20Pentagonal&category=%5BTile,%20Modified%5D#T=C) at a jumper offset would have created a serviceable bevel to have the staircase shafts guided up with relative smoothness. The design is as below:
[image: pentagonal guide with jumper offset]

Answer (score 2):

The thinnest curved lip I can think of is [Panel Curved 2 x 1 x 1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=89679) :

[image]

You'd still have to accommodate for the axle hole, but there appears to be room for that in your design (possibly just held by gravity).

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe smaller sloped elements than these exist:

[image]

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11477

And some wedged variants:

https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=29119
https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=29120

(1 module x 2 modules x 2 plates)
2 plates high overall but on average a little less.

Answer (score 0):

See [50950 Slope, curved, 3x1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=50950) and [61678 Slope, curved, 4x1](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=61678).

Comment: These suggestions are too thick for the overhang and the staircase. I need something that is about as thin as a flat plate but with a slope or edge.